# Autocomplete in Dojo using a textbox as opposed to a dropdown

Tags: autocomplete, dojo

Dojo's Autocomplete widget requires that I have a dropdown to start off with. Is there a way to create an autocomplete box in Dojo which starts out with a textbox like YUI's? I'm trying to use Dojo because that's what we use here in the project, also trying to modify existing JSP pages to have autocomplete. These pages don't have the fields as dropdowns (ie "select")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think dojox.form.MultiComboBox is what you are looking for.

Comment: checked it.. and trying to use it though ... Has lots of bugs. Can you suggest something else that is done similar to Facebook style autocomplete .

Answer (score 3):

New answer to an old question: The FilteringSelect widgit is a fairly robust auto-complete control.

The first example here shows a text field being used as the base element:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html