# Facebook style autocomplete using dojo

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, dojo, jquery-autocomplete

I found facebook style autocomplete using jQuery. But im using dojo framework for my web app. Can you suggest how to implement or any open source code available for autocomplete using dojo framework. ?

Using jquery :

http://devthought.com/wp-content/articles/autocompletelist/test.html

Comment: Can someone answer this question ....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autocomplete in Dojo using a textbox as opposed to a dropdown.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821051/autocomplete-in-dojo-using-a-textbox-as-opposed-to-a-dropdown)

Comment: Came across this now, related to my open question on the mailing list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using a dijit filtered select or dijit combobox, then updating the data from a search url as the user types in the input.

The filtered select and combobox use the dojo data api to load in a set of records, and then uses type ahead suggest for auto complete. If you reload a relevant set of records while the user types then you can provide useful options.

Also here is (older) one tutorial that goes over creating your own autocomplete widget:

http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/04/27/building-ajax-with-dojo-and-json.html#advanced-dojo

Another using dojo 1.6 with the zend framework, but you could adapt the widgets:

http://www.makina-corpus.org/blog/autocomplete-ajax-search-dojo-and-zend-framework